# Allow .htaccess only from one directory to another

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have mp3's in a directory called `/mp3/` and I want to be able to access them only from another `page.php` in another directory `/main/` on the site. 
No direct linking from outside.

All of the pages are written in `php`

I put this code in the `.htaccess` file inside the `/mp3/` directory...

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all

allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from localhost
allow from mydomain.com
allow from 123.45.678.90  # that's myserver's IP address (real one used in code)

Satisfy Any
```

But none of those work. 
It does work however if I use the IP address of were I am.

```
allow from 1.2.3.4  # my internet connection (real one used in code)
```

But that means it would work for anyone and their IP address.

What am I missing here? Does this work only on certain servers?
How do I make it use the server's IP address and not my IP address?

Comment: If you don't want something directly acessible, then DON'T put it inside your document root.

Comment: I don't think I have access outside of the root

Comment: then at least put them in some highly obscure subdirectory, and NEVER refer to that directory in anything that gets sent to the client. Can't access something when you don't know what its address/location is.

Comment: @MarcB [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is never a good solution though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into "hotlink protection" added to your .htaccess file. You can set it up for just .mp3 file extension, and forbid access by any foreign site or directly from browsers. You might even be able to restrict access from within your own site, but I can't see that being terribly useful.

Something like

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
# hotlink protection and allowed list
# don't forget to add https: to allow accesss for any with SSL
##  uncomment following line to PERMIT direct browser access of mp3 files
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com(/)?.*$     [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.mp3$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: I googled `hotlink protection` and found this `http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/` and their code worked

Answer (score 0):

Place the files you want to protect out of the public folder. This way they are only accessible via your scripts.

```
-root
--mp3s
--public_html
---main
----index.php
----page.php
```

Comment: I don't think I have access to outside root directory. Can I make a folder private?

Comment: in that case look at Jon Lin's answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to limit a "referral" and not direct access?

Denying from an IP limits **all** access, whether referred to by your page.php or by typing it into the browser's URL location bar. If you're trying to limit referrals, you can try using something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mp3/ - [L,F]
```

but be warned that referers can be spoofed.

Comment: Trying to stop direct access from outside.

Comment: @gravityboy when you have a page that has a link to a file in mp3, in order to load that file, it *must be directly accessible from the outside*, that is why you couldn't get it to work with `Deny` unless you added your own IP

Comment: I tested your code and I can link to and get the mp3 directly.

Comment: So that means I can't link access only from one page to another?

Comment: What does your code mean exactly? If referrer is not mydomain then do not goto mp3 folder?

Comment: @gravityboy it will return a 403 Forbidden if the referer isn't a link from yourdomain.com

Comment: I tested it and it is letting me link directly to mp3's without a referrer. It seems like yours should work but it isn't (for me anyway).

Comment: @gravityboy is the rules at the top of the htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: Everything is inside the mp3 folder. That is of course the only place I need to stop direct linking.

Comment: what does `RewriteRule ^mp3/ - [L,F]` exactly mean?

Comment: @gravityboy anything that starts with `mp3/` don't rewrite anything, just return a 403 Forbidden (the `F` flag)

Comment: It should be `deny any request not coming from this same domain`

Comment: @gravityboy your question specifically asks to deny requests for `mp3` (which is what the rule does), but if you want any request, just remove the `mp3/` part of the rule. That's gonna make it so the rule gets applied to page.php as well, which means if someone clicks on a link to page.php from google, they'll get 403 forbidden

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, in your `.htaccess`

```
<Files ~ ".mp3$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

This will not allow direct access to any files with `.mp3` from your web server.

Comment: Yes but I want to allow access from another page on my server. I Just stop direct access linking from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `mp3/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mp3/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(localhost|(www\.)?mydomain\.com)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```